# How long do you have — what does it mean?

Tags: american-english

„How long do you have?” — what does it mean?

The conversation regards my potential trip to another country to visit someone. It means how long I want to stay there?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. There are at least two distinct meanings that may apply, but it depends on the sequence of the conversation. Could you [edit] your question to add what was said immediately before "How long do you have?"

Answer (score 1):

They are asking how much time you have (or, how much time you have available) - implying that you need to be back on a certain day for some reason.

Other example sentences:

- How long do you have until school starts in the fall?
- How long do you have until your train leaves?
- How long do you have before your interview?

See also this answer - which I don't think is a duplicate, but tangentially answers your question:

["How much time" versus "how long"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86510/how-much-time-versus-how-long)